# What do I do about the "take the tour" invitation on the new meta account to make it go away?

Tags: bug

Normally with StackExchange, new users can click on the "take the tour" button to take the tour and earn the associated badge. But on this meta, it takes me to english.stackexchange.com/tour on the main site, not english.meta.stackedchange.com/tour on the meta site.

On the activity page, after clicking on the "take the tour" button, the badge offer remains on my profile. The mouseover link points to english.meta.stackexchange.com/tour, but redirects to the main site's tour at english.stackexchange.com/tour. Even entering the meta site's tour URL redirects to the main site's tour.

No action from this button can make it go away when clicked on the meta page as it does when clicked on from the normal site page.

How can I make it go away?

[image: Tour button]

...

Is this a bug or what else is going on? What am I missing?

Comment: I checked five sites and it doesn't matter if you click on the "take the tour" button on meta site, you are always directed to the main site, which makes sense, new users need to be familiar with the Stack Exchange model. So, no it doesn't look like a bug unless I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: You have not misibterpreted, but misread. Please reread the very last independent clause of the main paragraph.

Comment: No, it is exact and correct. I cannot take the tour that the button points to: english.meta.stackexchange.com/tour. That is both the problem and the title.

Comment: If it points to a tour that has already been taken, then the button is not necessary. Like dup questions, it should be removed. It seems that you disagree with me asking the question, not with the problem of a button that fails to recognize that the destination it points to has been reached.

Comment: No, you have not nor am I miffed. But, being miffed is off topic. The button offers an achievenent that you say ought to be a particular achievement, which has already been reached at a URL that redirects (though it seems you might not know how a URL redirect works, from how you respond). In web, UX & software dev, a button should represent its claim. Clicking neither goes to the URL linked to nor grants the promised achievement; it is either a bug in the server redirect settings or a UX inconsistency. It is a bug. And you are verbally aggressive in your many responses; post an answer or stop.

Comment: Jesse, your comment "you are verbally aggressive in your many responses" seems bizarre, as Mari-Lou's comments have been neutral in tone and helpful in approach, whereas your responses have been argumentative and unfriendly - the imperative "post an answer or stop" being an obvious example. If this trivial Tour labelling error or bug disturbs you, I recommend you post something on the main SE Meta site, since it appears to be a systemic SE matter.

Comment: @Chappo agrees that this is an SE meta-worthy bug; I may post one. However, there are many passive-aggressive communication habits in her speech. Google "passive-aggressive phrases" for examples. "...someone better than me do the explaining" is condescending for so many responses. She should have answered for vote, but instead kept posting "get-the-last-word" responses after I didn't agree. It's fine to make a point once, clarify it twice more, but to keep making one's point until people agree is called a filibuster. This is the first time I've seen someone do that anywhere on the forums.

Comment: Where are you seeing the link to the tour?

Comment: @Laurel Oh. I think I understand now. Do you think it is the welcome message that is plastered over the page for first time visitors? Is it plastered over meta too? Maybe the OP means that link, not the help button in the topbar.

Comment: @Laurel, it initially appears on the Activity page, just after joining the forum (or Q & A) saying something like "Get your first achievement, take the tour". The mouseover points to https://english.meta.se...com/tour, but redirects to http://english.se...com/tour, no award is given, and the same inviting button is still there when I return to the Activity page. On a non-meta, it would unlock the achievement and the button would be replaced by the "track the next one" message, but not with meta.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I want to be your friend, though I think you had bad form in assuming. Can we please work together to sort out our differences and help the overall community get along better. I am open and listening. And, Happy Thanksgiving all, I'm in Asia.

Comment: @Laurel btw, the URL for meta...tour itself won't work if entered directly, it is not just a problem with the button.

Comment: You've now explained the issue more clearly. I believed you were referring to the help button which is in the topbar. The message you saw is appears only once  for non-members. You should edit your post and add that detail in your answer. Glad that everything got cleared up.

Comment: There's no "tour" on the meta, and you seem to have found [the related bug report on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258179/the-new-profile-shouldnt-mistakenly-imply-that-you-can-earn-the-informed-badge)

Comment: Yes, there is a tour button on meta, also a url. Plz read the thread

Comment: Jesse, you’ll find this community much more sociable if you stop responding in such an abrasive manner. Or perhaps you’re unaware how your posts come across?

Comment: Let me rephrase it: there's only 1 version of tour on every site. Whether from the main site, or from meta site, even though they have different URL, both will redirect to the same tour. Once again, there's no (and never have been a)  specialized tour for meta. There's ["What's meta"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) only on the meta, but that's irrelevant to the tour. And as you have seen on the MSE, **yes, it's a bug**.

Comment: Then @Andrew T., the invitation to take the tour needs to be taken down for new users; it is a UX bug, not a server bug.

Comment: @JesseSteele yes, you're correct, but as you might have realized the MSE bug report since 2015, it hasn't been fixed. *We can't fix it either*, only SE employees can.

Comment: True. True. But, just doing Q & A... :-)

Comment: @Chappo you may be right. I'm open. But, I see a lot of passive-aggression and extra verbals that indicate conflict, and repeated pushing after a response has already been given. In my world, that doesn't fly with others. If that's allowed here tho, say so and I'll go along with it.

Comment: @AndrewT. Is SE developed here? https://github.com/StackExchange If so, then it's not only limited to employees and I could file a bug on GitHub.

Comment: @JesseSteele: The SE GitHub is run by SE employees in order to improve code that SE uses, but it contains only a few isolated, generic libraries. The majority of the SE codebase is proprietary.

Comment: I gather that from other places. Proprietary and Open Source each have their advantages, bugs being part of that discussion, but that changes topic and I won't go there.

Answer (score -1):

*This indeed seems to be a UX-related coding bug discussed elsewhere.* ***But, you can make it go away by getting the "Autobiographer" badge.***

Sometimes, this happens automatically. If not, you might try:

From the Meta's Activities page, click on "Main User" > "Edit Profile & Settings" > any "Save changes..." button... then wait a few minutes for the servers to populate. You should have the "Autobiographer" badge soon, thus the message will go away.

[image]

(There are neither profiles nor tours on meta sites.)